# How do I get dynamically fluid images depending on browser window aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, resize, aspect-ratio, fluid-layout, fluid-images

This might not be a simple question, but I try my best.

I have this example site: http://lotvonen.tumblr.com/
I have a little piece of javascript that automatically calculates the height of the inner browser window and sets that number as image wrapper div's height. Height of the image inside the wrapper is 100% of the wrapper, so that I get nice, full screen images on all normal screen sizes. 
This works wonderfully on screens that are more wide than tall (desktops, laptops, etc).

But!

With screens that are more tall than wide (smartphones, iPads etc), the images get clipped from sides. I don't want that, so I have a temporary solution to have media query assigning height to auto and width to 100%, when browser screen max-width is 1024, so that no clipping occurs. But it's not a very good solution, and breaks at certain resolutions. It also destroys my JS with lower resolutions (eg. 800x600).

Here's the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('img'),
size = elems.length;

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {

var img = elems[i];
var height = (window.innerHeight) ? window.innerHeight: document.documentElement.clientHeight;
img.style.height=(height)+'px';
}
</script>
```

and here's my CSS:

```
.img {
    max-width:100%
}
.img img {
    width:auto;
}
.img img {
    height:100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

.img {
    height:auto !important;
}
.img img {
    height:auto !important;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

and here's the div:

```
<li><div class="img"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/></div>
```

How do I get it so, that when the browser window is more tall than wide (eg. 720x1024), the images adjust by width, and when the browser window is more wide than tall (eg. 1024x720) the images adjust like they do now (by height, with the JS).
Is this possible at all? Is there a simple CSS fix to this or do I need to mess more with JS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also get the aspect in javascript on a regular basis and then add a class to the body object that would specify if it was 4:3, widescreen, or portrait. Then make it run on an interval in case the window changes size.

## Example

### CSS

```
.43 img { width: auto; }
.widescreen img { width: 100%; }
.portrait img { height: 100%; }
```

### JavaScript

```
var getAspect = function(){
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var aspect = w / h;

    var 43 = 4 / 3;
    var cssClass = "";

    if (aspect > 43) {
        cssClass = "widescreen";
    }
    else if (aspect === 43) {
        cssClass = "43";
    }
    else {
        cssClass = "portrait";
    }

    $("body").addClass(cssClass); // Using jQuery here, but it can be done without it
};

var checkAspect = setInterval(getAspect, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting the aspect ratio first in javascript. Use `window.innerHeight` and `windows.innerWidth`, and make the necessary division. Then, make this a condition. When the screen in wider than its height, set the image in css to `width: 100%`. Otherwise, set `height: 100%`.