# Css changing aspect ratio of fluid images

Tags: css, image, image-scaling

How can I crate a fluid image, but with an aspect ratio that I decide? (lets say 16:9)
I've already made it fluid with `max-width: 100%;` but I cant change the aspect ratio.

Note: the image has a different aspect ratio most of the times.

Comment: Did you want to change the proportion or is the image already is 16:9 format?

Comment: No the image has a different format. That's my main point.

Comment: You can't do that with CSS. You can either keep the existing ratio (by giving it a height of auto) or specify both the height and width with values in px or em etc. If you want more, use Javascript.

Comment: @MrLister Ok then i'll try and do it with javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrapp your image in two containers. Give one container `height:0` and a `padding-top` with the percentage you want for the height of your image in proportion to the width. So, for a height of 50% of the width use `padding-top:50%` and `height:0`, which - as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219005/proportionally-scale-a-div-with-css-based-on-max-width-similar-to-img-scaling) - will make the height proportional to the width by 50%.

```
.wrapper {padding-top:50%;height:0;position:relative;}
```

Inside of that container, you place another container with the following styling:

```
.inner{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;}
```

Now just place your image in the inner container and give it `width:100%` and `height:100%`

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/PREUD/1/
(updated the fiddle)

Comment: It works in chrome, firefox, ie9, and probably in ie8. Not sure about ie7, but what good stuff works well in ie7 :)

Comment: Great, the image is stretched 100% to the page or DIV. I just liked to bring others's attentions to the possibility of using 16:9 or 4:3 ratios instead of 50% value in "padding-top:50%". Foe example, to resize the image to 16:9 ratio (9/16), it can be "padding-top:56%", and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979520/how-do-i-get-dynamically-fluid-images-depending-on-browser-window-aspect-ratio):

## Example

### CSS

```
.43 img { width: auto; }
.widescreen img { width: 100%; }
.portrait img { height: 100%; }
```

### JavaScript

```
var getAspect = function(){
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var aspect = w / h;

    var 43 = 4 / 3;
    var cssClass = "";

    if (aspect > 43) {
        cssClass = "widescreen";
    }
    else if (aspect === 43) {
        cssClass = "43";
    }
    else {
        cssClass = "portrait";
    }

    $("body").addClass(cssClass); // Using jQuery here, but it can be done without it
};

var checkAspect = setInterval(getAspect, 2000);
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can do it with javascript, but I wanted to do it with css, because some users don't have javascript enabled.

Comment: @agam360 I didn't realize that you wanted only CSS. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, I am thinking to use javascript for now, so i'll take a look into it :) thanks

Answer (score -1):

It would probably require extra markup in the HTML, but you could use the CSS Clip property to  cut the visible portion of the image to what you would want to show. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clip