# JavaScript resize image to aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, image, aspect-ratio

I want to resize an image with lets say 980:1000 to an aspect ratio of 1:1, or an Image with 1500:900 to 16:9. 
How can I do that ?
I only want Images to get smaller so they dont get stretched
(980:1000 to for example 980:980).

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a browser? The easiest method is probably using background-size:cover.

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS?

To **Responsive Image**:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

_

[>StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399194/css-changing-aspect-ratio-of-fluid-images) ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/PREUD/1/))

[>Another tricks](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-useful-css-tricks-for-responsive-design)

[>Rundown of Handling Flexible Media](http://css-tricks.com/rundown-of-handling-flexible-media/)

[>Why Responsive Images Is So Hard](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-hard/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by placing the image inside a wrapper element and giving the size to wrapper and overflow property to hidden so that image appears to be cropped yet its not stretched.

`<div style="overflow:hidden; height:980px; width: 980px;" >
    <img src="img_1000x980.jpg" />
</div>`