# How to create an aspect ratio of 5x4 with an image which is not a background?

Tags: html, css

So I've been doing some research regarding aspect ratios and I am not understanding it very well.

I need an aspect ratio of `5x4` and I know that there is a css prop named `object-fit`.

So I applied that to my image component.

```
.image {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%
}
```

And that works good across screen resolutions.

But my question is; how do I achieve the 5x4 ratio? Like, what will be the `height` that I need to set to my component?

Comment: you need to put the image inside a div and make that div 5x4 and the image stretched inside

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio / https://stackoverflow.com/q/11399194/8620333

Comment: Hi @TemaniAfif you didn't understand my question. My question is that one; how do I know what is 5x4? Like, what is the height that I need to achieve that.

Comment: it means that the width will have 5 unit and the height only 4 unit so 1unit = height/4 and 1unit = width/5 ---> height = (4/5)*width and since you cannot express height based on width, you have the padding trick like explained in the question I linked.(ex padding-top: 80% )